# get cultureinfo with country code

Tags: ip-address, culture, cultureinfo

I try to get CultureInfo with country code. I'm using hostip.info for getting country code.

For example, "http://api.hostip.info/?ip=207.46.197.32&position=true" returns me "US" for country code or http://api.hostip.info/?ip=82.151.131.196&position=true returns "TR".

If I could have "en-US", "tr-TR", it's easy, but I can't have these culture names. I have country codes.

So is there any way to get CultureInfo with country codes or do you have any suggestion for getting CultureInfo with IP Address?

Answer (score 2):

If the request is made by a browser, the "Accept-Language" field in the HTTP request header will list desired culture(s). Granted, it's not from an IP, but it may be a solution if you have HTTP request headers.

E.g.,

Accept-Language: en-us,en

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can do this in practice.

If you have Switzerland, Canada or India  as country code which language would you want?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's better if I can get CultureName from IP Address? is there any way or what's the best way for localization with IP address?

Answer (score 1):

The official public standards is most better source to use.
See "CLDR - Unicode Common Locale Data Repository" at http://cldr.unicode.org/.

The datafiles are available for download. Interesting documentation and recommendations are available.

Comment: the 'likely subtag' section is what you want, specifically http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Likely_Subtags  and http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/likely_subtags.html

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, because I got the country code from a third-party IP localization library. So, here is my solution.

First I try to get the culture info by the country code. If this fails I retrieved all cultrure Info and then I search for the one that contains the country name (also possible the way is the country code (US) is contained in the `CultureInfo.Name` field (en-US))

```
ci = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Where(c => c.EnglishName.Contains(loc.countryName)).FirstOrDefault();
```

If the country have more than one culture then I followed the approach suggested by Doug Domeny